# Sqoop import failed "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"

Tags: sqoop

[image]Getting the below error while executing this command.
Attached my sqoop/lib folder files.

$ sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" --username root --password root

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: bad substitution
2020-04-26 13:14:51,257 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2020-04-26 13:14:51,393 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2020-04-26 13:14:51,627 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.initOptionDefaults(MySQLManager.java:73)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:89)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:33)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:51)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:30)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:46)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:31)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:38)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:31)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.<init>(MySQLManager.java:65)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.accept(DefaultManagerFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:184)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:272)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:44)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 20 more
```

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 8):

You have *common-lang3-3.4.jar* and `StringUtils` moved to `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`[[Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)]

In version 2.6 it used to be in `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`[[Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)]

You need to use [common-lang-2.6.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6)